# Meteor Iron-router custom user accounts system + redirects

Tags: symfony, meteor, iron-router

We're building a meteor app with Iron router on top of FOS Symfony2 user bundle.

Current attempt went as follows:

- On login app makes a http call to symfony API which creates a token and returns it. Symfony uses the same DB that meteor uses.
- The token is then stored as a persistent Session variable.
- Most views should be rendered only for logged-in users
- Looking at examples provided with iron router, I tried checking user in `onBeforeAction` and redirecting it with `this.render('Login');` when token is not valid and `this.next();` if token is existing.

That led to various problems; redirection is working, but it is really laggy.

My question is about any patterns i can follow or any ideas You have over is this a right way to do that.

Thank You for each suggestion

Comment: Is there any chance that the symfony API is being called for each redirection? Can you share your router code or at least the relevant parts of it?

Comment: @MichelFloyd Linked here is dirty draft partially sticked from what i have in a repo and what is yet to be commited and i remember by heart. Logic-wise should represent it right, but i have no way to verify that now (at home).

https://jsbin.com/sihehavofu/edit?js

Hope i didn't forget anything

Comment: @MichelFloyd it is possible to call symfony each change of view, but its also enough to compare token saved in session and the one at DB. Do you suggest calling symfony is better?

Comment: You definitely don't want to call out to a 3rd party API on every route change!!

Comment: I looked at your code, it seems redundant to have to both wait for the `userCollection` to load and to use the session variable. The session variable confirms the login by itself. This approach will always generate an extra wait. Since you're already using `u2622:persistent-session` you can use `Session.setAuth()` to have that session variable expire on logout.

Comment: @MichelFloyd, right, waitOn is not used anymore, but that makes no difference. Just forgot to remove it from repo. Thanks for the tip with Session.setAuth. Till now I was using set persistent('TOKEN', false).